# Laravel store files with different permission

Tags: 18.04, permissions, laravel

I'm trying to do resize my images with Invention image package. This package first retrieves the image and change it with old one after resizing it. But it can't change old image because laravel stores them with `570` permission.

Even if I set file permission to 777, laravel keep stores with 570. How do I fix this ?

images in storage directory

```
total 1140
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 982464 Eyl 21 00:34 6-1537128615.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 182859 Eyl 21 16:15 8-1537128615.jpg

total 1544
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 412899 Eyl 21 16:24 1-1537128615.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 982464 Eyl 21 00:34 6-1537128615.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 182859 Eyl 21 16:15 8-1537128615.jpg
```

Comment: "Even if I set file permission to 777" Why would you ever ever need executable permissions on a jpg? It should be 644 or 664 when dealing with regular files. Nothing more. `570` where do you see that in your example listing?

Comment: @Rinzwind  Yes I know, directories should 755 and files should be 644. I just giving an example.. I listed permissions with `ls -l` it says total permission is 1140. So there are two files.. I assumed one file has 570 permission ? Am I wrong ?